# What is the maximum post_max_size limit is recommended for WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPess site hosted on Amazon EC2 server, I have some files which have size upto 50-60 MB.

So is keeping the post_max_size 64M is recommended? Or maximum how much is recommended?

Comment: It purely depends on your needs. Are you going to upload simple images or big professional photo's, sharing pdf's or video's?

Comment: also depends on length of your posts characters wise. if you are posting pages or posts of 30 a4 pages of text you will need to increase that limit

Comment: "Recommended" for which use case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its depend on server settings but there is one thing always remember while setting upload_max_filesize <= post_max_size if you are not doing that will be throws an error.

For example, Your configuration allows user to upload 50MB file but you post_max_size is 20MB.That mean you request doesn't fullfill because you can post only 20MB for single request.

**Recommandations**

- To upload large files, post_max_size value must be larger than
  upload_max_filesize.
- memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size

**Guide line of PHP offical site**

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size